# If a product gh is in the kernel K of a homomorphism why g is in the coset made by the inverse of h and K

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a very straightfoward question, why if:
$$gh^{-1} \in \mathbf{K} \implies g \in h\mathbf{K}$$

Where $\mathbf{K}$ is the kernel of a homomorphism.

Also I am aware that the cosets $h\mathbf{K}$ and $\mathbf{K}h$ are the same because $\mathbf{K}$ s a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $gh^{-1} \in \mathbf K$.  It follows that 
$$
g = (gh^{-1})h \in \mathbf Kh = h\mathbf K
$$

Answer (score 0):

$ g = gh^{-1}h$.  Can you take it from here?